# Minimum value of a real valued function.

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Let $f:[0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|\ \forall\ \ x, y\in [0, 1].$$ Then how can we show the following?

(i) There exists a $x_0\in [0, 1]$ such that the function $$g:[0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}: g(x)=|f(x)-x|,$$ attains its minimum value.

(ii) Let $x_0$ be such that $$g(x_0)=\min_{x\in [0, 1]}g(x).$$ Then $f(x_0)\in [0, 1].$

I know that $g$ is a non-negative function. But how to ensure that minimum exists.

Comment: The assumption about $f$ implies that it is continuous and this in turn implies that $|f(x)-x|=g(x)$ is continuous. Then, $g$ is a continuous function on the compact interval $[0,1]$ which implies...

Comment: For $i)$: are you familiar with the notion of a continuous function on a compact domain? If so, since $[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, we know that $g$ *must* attain a maximum and minimum value.

Comment: @Taylor Rendon Yes, I am familiar with the same.

Comment: Do you know what is a contraction is a complete metric space and contraction mapping principle (or Banach fixed point theorem), which guarantees the existence of a fixed point of a contraction.

Comment: @MittalG - Good to hear! Do you have any questions about what I wrote or does that answer your $i)$?

Comment: No part (i) is clear. Please answer part (ii).

Comment: Perhaps there is some condition missing. Otherwise let $f(x)=0.5x+10000000$.